# How to execute command in a C# Windows console app?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, console-application

How to implement this pseudo code in a C# Windows console app?

```
for i=1 to 100
    rename filei newFilei
```

The key goal is to loop and execute any cmd command within a Windows console app.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string strCmdLine;
        System.Diagnostics.Process process1;
        process1 = new System.Diagnostics.Process();


        Int16 n = Convert.ToInt16(args[1]);
        int i;
        for (i = 1; i < n; i++)
        {
            strCmdLine = "/C xxxxx xxxx" + args[0] + i.ToString();
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", strCmdLine);
            process1.Close();
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: show the code you have written...

Comment: Does this even compile? This looks like a gross translation from Java

Comment: You may consider changing your question to `Can I repeatedly execute commands on windows command prompt "DOC" using C#?`.

Comment: ***Please*** stop prefacing your questions with tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Diagnostics.Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx)

```
            System.Diagnostics.Process proc;

            cmd = @"strCmdLine = "/C xxxxx xxxx" + args[0] + i.ToString();

            proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            proc.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
            proc.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd";
            proc.StartInfo.Arguments = cmd;
            proc.Start();
```

Answer (score 1):

C# supports four different loop constructs:

1. [for](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch45axte.aspx)
2. [foreach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)
3. [while](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2aeyhxcd%28VS.71%29.aspx)
4. [do](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/370s1zax.aspx)

The documentation for each of these is sufficiently detailed that I won't explain these again here.

File related operations can be performed with the [File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.aspx) and [Directory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.aspx) classes respectively. For example to rename a file you could use the Move method of the File class like so.

`File.Move("oldName","NewName");`

Because both `oldName` and `NewName` are assumed to be in the same directory, the file named `oldName` is renamed to `NewName`.

With respect to launching other applications the [Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) class offers the ability to launch a process and monitor it's execution. I'll leave investigating this class and it's capabilities to the reader.

The pseudo-code included in the question could be translated to the following code in C#. Please note that this sample does not include any error handling which one will always want to include in production code.

```
string[] sourceFileNames=new string[100];
string[] destFileNames = new string[sourceFileNames.Length];
//fill arrays with file names.
for (int i=0; i < fileNames.Length; i++)
{
File.Move(sourceFileNames[i], destFileNames[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you're doing is renaming files you can do that by using the `System.IO.File` class with the `Move` method

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.move.aspx

Comment: No, renaming is just an example. I have added a portion of code that I am working on to the original question.