# How to execute console app using multiple threads c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

I want to execute application using multiple threads using c#

I tried like below for normal method what about app execution ?

```
 public static void OneThread()
        {
            DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;

            Thread t11 = new Thread(() =>
            {
                for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
                {
                    var proc = new Process();
        proc.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Users\consoleapp.exe";
        proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "-v -s -a";
        proc.Start();
        proc.WaitForExit();
        var exitCode = proc.ExitCode;
        proc.Close();
                }
            });

            t11.Start();
            t11.Join();
            Console.WriteLine("execution 1 thread 5 times in {0} seconds", (DateTime.Now - startTime).TotalSeconds);

        }
```

Comment: I want to run code for scenarios like - 
`5 thread execute  1 application`
currently i'm doing one thread run method 5 times.

Comment: So your problem is nothing to do with threads. You just want to know how to execute a console app from a .NET program?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to execute command in a C# Windows console app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6798547/how-to-execute-command-in-a-c-sharp-windows-console-app)

Comment: i want to use multiple thread also while executing c# I tried like this - updated question,,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if I understood the question correctly. This code has n threads which execute the same method

```
int n = 5;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    Thread t = new Thread(MethodToExecute);
    t.Start();
}


public void MethodToExecute()
{
    Process process = new Process();
    // Configure the process using the StartInfo properties.
    process.StartInfo.FileName = "pathToConsoleApp.exe";
    process.Start();
    process.WaitForExit();// Waits here for the process to exit.
}
```

Comment: instead of executing method I want to call console app using that thread , how to do it?

Comment: I updated my answer. Now it creates 5 threads, which create 5 processes and opens the console app 5 time. But in this case i think a thread is not needed. You could directly create 5 processes